# How to loop with *ngFor in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm learning Angular2, so please forgive me if I'm asking a stupid question. I am receiving an arrays of objects and it looks like this:

obj.json

```
data: [
        {
           item: "banana"
        }
     ],
     [
        {
           item: "apple"
        }
     ],
     [
        {
           item: "lemon"
        }
     ]
```

In my component file I have managed to scope it in a scope:

```
this.fruits = data[0].item;
```

The issue is I only manage to scope the first item, or the second item and so on, by the index. How can I scope them all and then show them in a HTML file with `*ngFor`?

Comment: This is an invalid object.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your array isn't valid JavaScript. Assuming your data actually looks like this:

```
data: [
        {
           item: "banana"
        },
        {
           item: "apple"
        },
        {
           item: "lemon"
        }
     ]
```

Then you'll iterate through the data like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let fruit of data">
   <b> {{fruit.item}} </b>           
</li>
```

Comment: I didn't place the all objects, but there are many other keys besides the key item. What is important to me is how I can loop through arrays, via index, to get them all. Please note that I don't know what is the number of indexex.

Comment: @tholo The problem is not the number of keys, but the placement of the square brackets. You basically have a list of arrays of single objects, which is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: you didn't understand me. I don't have a list of arrays of single objects, I have other objects there as well, but I didn't name them as they are not significant for my example..

Comment: Forget about the objects for a second, then your declaration looks like this: `data: [],[],[]`. That's not valid JavaScript. You can have `data: [[],[],[]]`(array of arrays) or `data: []` (array), but not what you showed.

Answer (score 4):

Your object isn't valid. I've edited it.

To iterate over object properties, use:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='let elem of data'>{{ elem.item }}</li>
</ul>
```

**[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/AEV9e0eMr9g72uawcQ9Q)**

Answer (score 1):

```
export class SomeClass {
    public name: String;
    constructor(_name: String){
       this.name= _name;
    }
}    

let fruits : Array<SomeClass>[new SomeClass("banana"),new SomeClass("apple"),new SomeClass("lemon")];


<li *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
   <b> {{fruit.name}} </b>           
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly see the problem. I'm using this as well.

I have an array of objects: `private receipts:receipt[]` where receipt is an object that contains some relevant data

```
export class receipt {
    public imageData;
    private accountNo;
    private tripNo;
    private ticketType;
    //..getters/setters and other variables
}
```

Now after filling the array I simply use it like this (nevermind the ion-slides, this does work for divs as well):

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let entry of receipts; let i = index" id="{{'imgSlideContainer_'+i}}">
     <div>
        <img src="{{entry.getImageData()}}" id="{{'imgSlide_'+i}}" (click)="openImageUtil(entry, 'imgSlide_'+i)">
     ...
</ion-slide>
```

This behaves as expected. For form, you can also use `{{entry.imageData}}` if it's an accessible property (Yes, I tested this)

Similarily for nested Objects you should be able to simply `{{entry.someSubObject.someSubSubObject}}`

Hope this helps.