# How to bind array of object using *ngFor in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

```
{
    "Search": [
        {
            "name": "akram",
            "roll": 101
        },
        {
            "name": "wasim",
            "roll": 102
        }
    ],
    "total": "two record"
}
```

I want to print like this:

```
akram 101
wasim 102
```

Comment: What did you try so far? See [How to loop with `*ngFor` in array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400154/how-to-loop-with-ngfor-in-array-of-objects)

Comment: yest but my object is different as your object can you see below my object

{"Search":[
{"name":"akram","roll":101},
{"name":"wasim","roll":102}
],"total":"two record"}

Answer (score 5):

Just use this:

```html
<p *ngFor="let item of object.Search">{{item.name}} {{item.roll}}</p>
```

See [the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Comment: <li *ngFor="let movie of movieListItem.Search">
Cannot read property 'Search' of undefined
Error occurs in the template of component MoviedasboardComponent.

Comment: What error, do you need to capitalize movieListItem.Search

Comment: ----------Below is the code------------ 
.ts
public movieListItem:movieItem[] : data store from subscribe method

.service
getList(): Observable<movieItem[]> {
    return this.http.get<movieItem[]>(this.movieRender);
  }

.html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let movie of movieListItem.Search">
        {{movie.Title}}
    </li>
</ul>

Comment: can you put the error message and the code into the question

Comment: Property 'Search' does not exist on type 'movieItem[]'.

5     <li *ngFor="let movie of movieListItem.Search">

Comment: The array can't have the object Search, either you use an object that has the property Search or just write `*ngFor="let movie of movieListItem"`